# How do I build Google smart home action that only need to communicate with my IoT Gateway?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-smart-home

As I looked into Google's references about smart home, I got to know that Google Home connects directly with the end device. But I wanted to specifically connects it with my gateway and sync with it so Google Assistant would only need to send command to the gateway to fulfill a user's request like "Turn on the light". Is this possible or Google need to connect to every end devices for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can create a Hub device that talks to the Cloud and acts as a gateway to smaller, low-powered devices. In that case, you would still return all of your devices [in the SYNC response](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/process-intents#SYNC) but then handle all of the [EXECUTE requests](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/process-intents#EXECUTE) in your Cloud by forwarding to the Hub. From there the Hub can handle it however is needed.